# How to find patterns in a line and print the result using UNIX sed?

Tags: unix, sed

If I have a line something like this:`1300397,0,3,86,some more text here,end writing, another string here` and I want to display `86 end writing` only, how can I do that using sed?

So far I have this: `sed 's/.*\(8[4-6]\).*/\1/' job_details.txt` which only displays `86`. How can I include `end writing` string?

Desired result:
`86 end writing`

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: With awk would be just `echo "1300397,0,3,86,some more text here,end writing" | awk -F, '{print $4, $6}'`

Comment: @fedorqui if you check his sed codes, he doesn't know the 86 will always be in $4.

Comment: Yes, you are right @Kent. Anyway it is not clear where and what condition should we have for it apart from it starting with `8`. Maybe an `echo 86` would do the trick :)

Comment: Hi Fedorqui, while this works for this particular example, I think it won't for multiple lines with 86 and end writing aren't on the same column. Really appreciate your response. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this line should work:

```
awk -F, '{for(x=1;x<=NF;x++)f=$x~/^8[4-6]$/?$x:f;print f,$NF}'
```

**note** that, the above line checks a field/column if it **equals** `8[4-6]`. for example, `86` will be printed, but `88886 or foo86bar or 8622222` won't be printed. if you just want to check if the column **contains** `8[4-6]` remove the `^ and $` from the one-liner.

with your example:

```
kent$ echo "1300397,0,3,86,some more text here,end writing"|awk -F, '{for(x=1;x<=NF;x++)f=$x~/^8[4-6]$/?$x:f;print f,$NF}'
86 end writing
```

**EDIT**

try this:

```
awk -F, '{for(x=1;x<=NF;x++){f=$x~/^8[4-6]$/?$x:f;e=e?e:$x=="end writing"}print f, (e?"end writing":"")}'
```

Comment: Hi Kent, thanks for the prompt response. I haven't tried your code yet but it looks like it's going to print 86 and the last line which is end writing? What happens if there are more strings following 'end writing'? Sorry I should've brought this up above.

Comment: please update your question with a better example pls. your example lets me assume that you want to take 86 and the last column.

Comment: Thanks Kent, will try it on my vm workstation as soon as I get home. Can't try it here at work. :D

Comment: Appreciate your help @Kent I prefer sed, so this code worked for me: `sed -n '/8[4-6],.*end writing/s/^.*\(8[4-6],.*end writing\).*$/\1/p' file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

```
 sed -nr '/^.*(8[4-6]).*(end writing).*$/{s//\1 \2/;p}' job_details.txt
```